# OpenVPN: Get IP from the router's network

Tags: networking, router, vpn, openvpn

### Background

I have this configuration:

> Internet <--> router <--> laptop

My `laptop` has `openvpn` installed. Listening on port 9999. The `router` has port forwarding from port 9999 to my `laptop`.

My laptop is getting the IP address `192.168.1.2` from my router. Static IP.

I created a client certificate for testing. Add an external computer and he was able to connect my internal network, using the VPN tunnel.

My external VPN user getting the IP address `10.0.0.2`.

### The Question

I want to create a situation that the external client will get IP address from the router's network (for example: `192.168.1.3`), instead of from the openvpn's network (`10.0.0.2`). So this user will looks like any other users on my router internal network.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically possible, but not really recommended – in most cases you should instead just get inter-subnet routing working correctly.

There are two ways, and which one to use depends on *why* you want the clients to look "like any other user", as having an IP address is just part of what makes a device be within the same subnet – do you need the ability to send/receive broadcasts? do you need the ability to send/receive non-IP packets?

#### Bridging

In this method, VPN clients "directly" connect to the same Ethernet broadcast domain – they can get an address through DHCP, they can send broadcasts, they can even send non-IP packets. The VPN server acts like a switch.

1. Switch the OpenVPN service to bridge mode:

   ```
   dev tap
   server-bridge
   ```

   All clients must use `dev tap` too.
2. Create the actual bridge at OS level. On Linux this can be done using `ip link` and `bridge` commands, although older tutorials which talk about `brctl` are still valid as well.

   The manual (temporary) setup would look like this:

   ```
   ip link add br0 type bridge
   ip link set br0 up
   ip link set tap0 master br0
   ip link set eth0 master br0

   ip -4 addr flush dev eth0
   ip -4 addr add 192.168.1.2/24 dev br0
   ip -4 route add default via 192.168.1.1 dev br0
   ```

   Note that *both* the VPN 'tap' interface and the physical Ethernet interface are put in the bridge.

   Doing this "permanently" depends on how your existing network is configured – e.g. on Debian you would add the bridge in `/etc/network/interfaces`, on Ubuntu you would use netplan, etc.

Bridging with OpenVPN is well documented elsewhere:

- https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/

#### Proxy ARP

In this method, the VPN clients only get addresses from the same range, but they are still separate at layer-2 (with the VPN server still acting as a router between the two).

The advantage is that this works with Android/iOS clients, which cannot use the Ethernet 'tap' mode due to OS limitations. (The absence of broadcasts saves their battery life, too – a LAN sometimes has a surprising amount of junk packets being sent around.)

1. Configure the VPN service to have a smaller prefix (e.g. a /27) that's within the LAN range.

   ```
   dev tun
   topology subnet
   server 192.168.1.192 255.255.255.224
   ```

   You should end with something like this on the VPN server, with the address ranges intentionally overlapping:

   ```
   eth0 = 192.168.1.2/24
   tun0 = 192.168.1.193/27
   ```
2. Either enable the proxy-ARP feature that Linux kernel has built-in, or install the 'parpd' daemon which does the same thing on its own. (Personally I find parpd easier to understand and configure.)

   For example, this will cause Linux to answer *all* ARP queries that arrive through eth0 and ask for an address that belongs to some other interface:

   ```
   sysctl net.ipv4.conf.eth0.proxy_arp=1
   ```

   parpd, meanwhile, is configured like this:

   ```
   interface eth0
       proxy 192.168.1.192/27
   ```

Now your LAN's other devices think that VPN clients are in the same subnet, based on their address. When they try to make an ARP query, the VPN server will answer on the client's behalf.